# Celery task creating duplicate queues on high load

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, redis, celery

We have a shared task name create_child in celery and binding with queue child_A be below definition..

```
@shared_task(bind=True, queue="child_A")
def create_child(self, **kwargs):
```

When there is high load on create_child task we are experiencing in redis there is two queues got created. One is **"_kombu.binding.child_A"** and second is child_A. This causes some data loss and also after some time there is no data coming in celery worker, because the queue is not cleared.

We are using redis as a broker for celery.
**Python version: 3.10**
**Celery version: 5.2.7**